# Why does this model return "non-object error", when it worked in the controller?

Tags: php, debugging, codeigniter

In my controller I went from getting the data right there (which worked fine):

```
$data['query'] = $this->db->query("MY DB QUERY");  
$this->load->view('shopci_view', $data);
```

to grabbing the data from a class model function:

```
    class Shopci_model extends CI_Controller {

      function __construct()
      {
        parent::__construct(); //model constructor
      }

      //display sale itmes on shopci_view.php
      function sale_items()
      {    

        $query = $this->db->query('MY DB QUERY - SAME AS ABOVE');

        return $query->result();
      }

  }
```

new controller function:

```
//load model, auto connect to db
$this->load->model('Shopci_model', '', TRUE);    
//Display items for sale
$data['query'] = $this->Shopci_model->sale_items();  
$this->load->view('shopci_view', $data);
```

ERROR:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in
>   shopci_view

This is the line in the view that worked before I switched to the model (didn't change view):

```
<?php foreach($query->result() as $row): ?>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model you return the $query as a result() array to the controller.

So you cannot then use 'foreach $query->result()' again - because you have already done that;

This should work

```
  <?php foreach($query as $row): ?>
```

OR if you want - just change the model from

```
 return $query->result();
```

to

```
 return $query;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your model you want to return the data to pass to the controller. So in your model you would have

```
function sale_items()
{
    $query = $this->db->query(SAME AS OLD);
    return $query;
}
```

and then your controller will be the same and your foreach in your view should be the following

```
<?php foreach ($query as $row): ?>
```